# PHP Implode array chunk automatic?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

i have array chunk,

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => "0"
        [1] => "1"
        [2] => "2"
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [3] => "3"
        [4] => "4"
        [5] => "5"
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [5] => "5"
        [6] => "6"
        [7] => "7"
    )
```

)

i want to implode automatic this array with looping, and get format

```
012|345|567
```

Comment: You want to get the string "012|345|567" from this array?

Answer (score 3):

Try using implode + array_map:

```
$array = array ( array(1,2,3), array(4,5,6), array(7,8,9));
$array = implode('|', array_map('implode', $array));
print_r($array);
```

Comment: @Chielarck You are welcome. Always help future visitors by selecting the answer you like best as the accepted answer.

Comment: I needed a variant of this where I wanted to implode but also include a separator; I don't think you can use array_map because you can't pass the separator parameter. I used array_walk($arr, 'apply_implode', ','); with function apply_implode(&$element, $key, $separator){  $element = implode($separator, $element);} and note that array_walk does NOT RETURN an array like array_map does

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.

```
function implode_array($param = array()) {
  $result = '';
  foreach ($param as $p1_key => $p1_value) {
    $result .= implode("", $p1_value);
    if ($p1_key < count($param))
      $result .= '|';
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code,

```
$array = Array(
[0] => Array
(
    [0] => "0"
    [1] => "1"
    [2] => "2"
)
[1] => Array
(
    [3] => "3"
    [4] => "4"
    [5] => "5"
)
[2] => Array
(
    [5] => "5"
    [6] => "6"
    [7] => "7"
)

);

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
     $keys[] = implode("",array_keys($value));
}
$result = implode('|', $keys);
```

Thanks!